# How to set the default placeholderImage when using fresco

Tags: android, android-layout, fresco

I custom the SimpleDraweeView in my project, and the placeholderImage is using much time in my project, so I want to set the default placeholderImage, and I can remove the fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_img_loading" in my xml.

```
<my.packagename.CustomDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/iv_img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_img_loading" />
```

I also tried to add this code in my CustomDraweeView

```
getHierarchy().setPlaceholderImage(R.drawable.ic_img_loading)
```

but it did not work when I added

```
fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/ic_img_loading"
```

in my xml. Is there any way to know the xml add the fresco:placeholderImage